# imshow window cannot be reused when called within a thread in raspberry pi

Tags: python, opencv

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
import time
import datetime
from threading import Timer
from threading import Thread

def showVideo(capl, secs):
    time.sleep(secs)
    try:
        print("start video")
        while(capl.isOpened()):
            ret, frame = capl.read()
            cv2.namedWindow('frames', cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
            cv2.setWindowProperty('frames', cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
            try:
                cv2.imshow('frames',frame)
                print("imshow")
            except:
                break

            if cv2.waitKey(50) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break

        capl.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        print("End video")

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def bootProgramm():
    fileList = os.listdir('source/')
    getLength = len(fileList)
    i= 0
    print(fileList)
    while (i <= (getLength - 1)):
        print(fileList[i])
        #secs = 10
        #print(secs)

        x=datetime.datetime.now()
        y=x.replace(year=2018, month=10, day=9, hour=14, minute=(46+i), second=0, microsecond=0)
        delta_t = y - x
        secs = delta_t.seconds+1

        capl = cv2.VideoCapture('source/'+fileList[i])
        #showVideo(capl, secs)
        Thread(target = showVideo, args = (capl, secs)).start()    
        #Timer(secs, showVideo, [capl]).start()
        i=i+1


bootProgramm()
```

This is the code. Only the 1st video is showing, I didn't see any error. Why it is not working in raspberry? The same program works fine in Windows, but not in the raspberry. Does anyone know why? please help, I am stuck in it for many days. Thank you.

Comment: so you create several threads to show several videos, in the same imshow frame?  which you create in each frame and destroy for each video.... this sounds like race conditions everywhere.... Maybe you should say what you want to achieve, it looks like displaying several videos in fullscreen at the same time,is not what you want to achieve.

Comment: i am displaying several videos at diffrent times, and i also destryoing frames. the program is working well on windows, but not on raspberry, why.?

Comment: Still it sounds better to do it all in the same thread, instead of creating threads and sleeping inside each of them... However it may depend on how did you install opencv, and which libraries is using in the background for displaying.  Maybe you can try creating the window in the main thread and not destroying the window every video?